# EOFs T mode vs S mode

Tags: meteorology, statistics

Do you know what is the difference between EOFs S mode and T mode? I want to find the spatial patterns and I have a time series for values at each location.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is just the spatial mode and the temporal mode. These kind of questions would be better off on scicomp SE